# mPDF footer image not scaling

Tags: php, html, image, footer, mpdf

In mPDF 6.1.4, the footer image (if defined as a background image in a div) does not scale anymore and ends up being 1:1 in scale, which is often wrong.

This is the HTML for my footer:

```html
<div style="background:white url(images/footer.jpg) no-repeat top center;">
  This is my footer with a BG
</div>
```

I then set this footer using **$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter()**, but because the image is 3000 x 600px, you only see a portion of it in the resulting pdf.

I've already tried **background-image-resize:6** (etc.) but that has no effect (the header displays the above footer HTML perfectly by the way). The only fix I can find is to add **background-size:100%**, but I'm curious why this isn't needed in the header. Plus I have around 200 footers in my database that I'd rather not alter.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: is your `background-repeat` and `background-position` in the wrong order? don’t know if there is anything wrong with that though.

Comment: Also did you specified the width and height when doing 'background-resize`? Just curious.

Comment: I've tried different combinations but it has the same result. Its annoying because this all worked in mPDF 6.0, but the move to 6.1.4 seems to have broken a couple of things.